# limit results of each in handlebars.js

Tags: jquery, html, handlebars.js

I have written a small plugin that displays tweets. following is the code that loops and displays the tweets.

```
    <script id="tweets-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template" >
        {{#each this}}
        <li>
        <p>{{tweet}}</p>
            <span id="author">{{author}}<span/>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

But what I want to do is limit the number of tweets to 5 or 10. But the loop is listing all the available tweets. How do I limit the tweets like in for loop. like

```
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){display the tweets}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you have two options:

1. Limit the size of your collection before handing it to Handlebars.
2. Write your own block helper that lets you specify a limit.

The actual [`each` implementation](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/base.js#L57) is pretty simple so adapting it to include an upper limit is fairly straight forward:

```
// Warning: untested code
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_upto', function(ary, max, options) {
    if(!ary || ary.length == 0)
        return options.inverse(this);

    var result = [ ];
    for(var i = 0; i < max && i < ary.length; ++i)
        result.push(options.fn(ary[i]));
    return result.join('');
});
```

Then in your template:

```
<script id="tweets-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template" >
    {{#each_upto this 5}}
        <li>
            <p>{{tweet}}</p>
            <span id="author">{{author}}<span/>
        </li>
    {{/each_upto}}
</script>
```

Comment: Each is now more complicated, and passes along additional contextual information.  Using a subexpression in exactly the way talkol defines it is more flexible and probably more future-proof, ensuring that things inside the #each block will have access to all the features that core helper exposes.

Comment: This was very useful and I was able to get it working after I remembered to update the closing block from `/each` to `/each_upto`.

Answer (score 27):

I agree that duplicating `each` is currently not a good idea, as [Dtipson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21993334/1025458) says.

His proposed approach with the `limit` helper is indeed the best way IMO, here is the code needed to implement it:

```
// limit an array to a maximum of elements (from the start)
Handlebars.registerHelper('limit', function (arr, limit) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) { return []; }
  return arr.slice(0, limit);
});
```

And then in your template (assuming your array is `cart.products`):

```
{{#each (limit cart.products 5)}}
  <li>Index is {{@index}} - element is {{this}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

You need a recent handlebars version that supports sub-expressions for this to work of course.

Comment: What about when 5 is a handlebars var?

Answer (score 4):

"each" is no longer very simple: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/base.js#L99

That's because each now supports a whole host of loop information you probably want to still have access to.

So limiting the data early on is probably preferable if you don't want to reimplement the much more complicated each.   You could also try using a subexpression within each (i.e. a {{#each (limit data 6)}} if you're using the latest version of handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    <div>
        {{#each react}}
            {{#ifCond @index '<' 5}} 
                <h3>{{@index}} {{name}}</h3></a>
            {{/ifCond}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
```

**Define ifCond:**
helper.js:

```
var helper = {};
module.exports = helper;

helper.ifCond = function (v1, operator, v2, options) {   
    switch (operator) {
        case '==':
            return (v1 == v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '===':
            return (v1 === v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '!=':
            return (v1 != v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '!==':
            return (v1 !== v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<':
            return (v1 < v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<=':
            return (v1 <= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>':
            return (v1 > v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>=':
            return (v1 >= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '&&':
            return (v1 && v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '||':
            return (v1 || v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        default:
            return options.inverse(this);
    }
};
```

In App.js:

```
const helper = require('./helper/helper');
app.engine('hbs', handlebars({
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',
  extname: 'hbs',
  helpers: helper
}));
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just have a look at the `{{@index}}` value and wrap it in an `{{#if}}` block. If the index if greater than an certain number then don't render the markup.

```
var collection = { ... tweets ... }

{{#each collection}}
    {{#if @index < 5}}
        <tweet markup>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: appreciate your answer, helped me out.