# iterate through an array less then specific number of times

Tags: handlebars.js, client-templates

I am using Handlebars.js as js templates. And I need to iterate through the array but not until the array will finish, but less than specific number of times.

So suppose I have a following JSON:

```
{
    "obj":
        [
            {"user": "Fred", "age": "23", "type": "personal"},
            {"user": "Ralph", "age": "32", "type": "business"},
            {"user": "John", "age": "44", "type": "other"},
            {"user": "Alex", "age": "44", "type": "other"},
            {"user": "Stan", "age": "6", "type": "other"},
            {"user": "Cartman", "age": "5", "type": "other"},
            {"user": "Kennie", "age": "6", "type": "other"}
        ]
}
```

But I need to output only first 4 users, so Stan, Cartman and Kennie will not be there.
If I would need to iterate everything I would use something like this:

```
<ul>
    {{#each obj}}
    <li>
        <div>{{this.user}}</div>
        <div>{{this.age}}</div>
        <div>{{this.type}}</div>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

How can I modify it?

Question 2:
Currently I am using obj only for the reason, that I was not able to figure out how to iterate JSON which consists only from array:

```
        [
            {"user": "Fred", "age": "23", "type": "personal"},
            {"user": "Ralph", "age": "32", "type": "business"}
        ]
```

How can I change my template to iterate without that pesky obj?

Comment: possible duplicate of [limit results of each in handlebars.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377700/limit-results-of-each-in-handlebars-js) or at least part I is, part II should be a separate question.

Comment: The two most common Handlebars answers boil down to (1) write a custom helper and (2) preprocess your data. Don't be afraid to poke around the Handlebars source code to see how it implements the standard helpers, they're pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out the way to solve question 2:

Using `this` solves the problem

```
<ul>
    {{#each this}}
    <li>
        <div>{{this.user}}</div>
        <div>{{this.age}}</div>
        <div>{{this.type}}</div>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

As for the first question, apparently there is no way to do this natively with handlebar.js so I am thinking how to write my own Helper for this.

PS. Thanks to **mu is too short** for showing the answer for the first part:
[limit results of each in handlebars.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377700/limit-results-of-each-in-handlebars-js)