# Emberjs-data Limit collections

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have this jsbin, is a relly littl modification of the todos example

http://jsbin.com/ubimes/1/

I'm trying to find the way to limit a model to the last 5 entries

```
 return Todos.Todo.find({limit:5});
```

But that query returns nothing

Any idea how to limit collections ?

Comment: do you want the limit to take place in the client or the server?

Comment: I think is best on the server, but whatever is more easy

Comment: if it has to be easier, then you should do it in the client, ember data does not provide such a feature `limit` out of the box, there would be workarounds, but filtering your collection in the client would be way easier and straight forward...

Comment: any idea on how do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way you could do it could be limiting your collection's content in your respective controller holding the data, like this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  limitedContent: function() {
    // in this case '2' is the limit parameter
    return this.get('content').splice(0, 2);
  }.property('content')
});
```

The `.property('content')` defines a binding to the controller's content and takes care that the `#each` helper rerenders when the `content` changes.

And then in your template you loop over the `limitedContent` rather then the `content`:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#each color in limitedContent}} 
    {{color.name}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

And here a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ajopah/7/edit) that show the concept mentioned.

Hope it helps

Comment: Perfect !!! ALso I found other way I just post it here as alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377700/limit-results-of-each-in-handlebars-js

Comment: I had to do `return this.get('content').content.splice(0,10);` to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use slice instead of splice

> this.get('content').slice(0, 2);