# Manipulating data from store

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'd like to manipulate the data I get from the `store` object (`this.store.find('...')`, etc.), like limiting (I can't just send a limit to the API, since I'm just using fixtures at the moment) or reversing the result.

For limiting I've already tried to implement a `limit` helper and call it in the `each` block (`#each (limit recentItems 5) ...`);

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.helper(function(params) {
  return params[0].slice(0, params[1]);
});
```

I don't know exactly why it didn't work, but it seems that the result object is not an array and therefore I'm not able to slice it. Same goes for reverting.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the result of store.find ?

Comment: @kristjanreinhold I'm a bit confused. The result is just an object - what do you want to see? Interestingly a comment disappeared, but yes, I did see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077649/emberjs-data-limit-collections, but I have multiple models - therefore `this.get('content')` doesn't return what I need.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html  try findAll('xx/xx') does it still return an object. The result should definitely by n array. are you sure you're not using find('x/y', 1) ?

Comment: Oh, I am using `this.store.find('...', id)`, since I need to pass the ID. Is there a difference in the outcoming object?

Comment: Lol you wot mate? You are quering for an Object. And then you try to apply array prototype functions on it ? Does your object contain of any array maybe? Result : {  someRelatedItems  : [] }

Comment: The object I get is actually a promise. Is there no way to convert the fulfilled promise into an array or something like that? I don't know, but this seems confusing to me so far.

Comment: I mean you can convert it to array, but if array contains of 1 item. then you dont need to user to show 5 first items because you always have only 1 item. lol. How about you post some simplified JSON and expected output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92152/discussion-between-kristjan-reinhold-and-nehalist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manipulating the model is exactly what the `afterModel` method on your route is for.

It get's passed your resolved model (so you don't have to worry about promises) and you can modify it to your heart's content.

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(model, transition) {
    // Modify the model here
  }
});
```

[afterModel documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel)

**EDIT:** *Additional suggestion after discussion in comments...*

If you want to fetch an additional model (outside of the model hook) and have it accessible on the controller then you could fetch it in the setupController hook on your route, and modify it in there before setting it on the controller.

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {

  // Default functionality
  this._super(controller, model);

  // Create items ArrayProxy and set it on the controller
  var arr = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({});
  controller.set('recentItems', arr);

  // Fetch additional model
  this.store.find('items').then(function(items) {

    // Promise has resolved by this point

    var i = 0;

    // Iterate over first 5 returned items

    while (i < 5) {

      // Add each item to recentItems property on controller
      controller.get('recentItems').addObject(items[i]);

    }

  });

}
```

[setupController documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController)

Comment: I think I might used the wrong wording. I don't want to manipulate the model directly, but instances of it. E.g.: I get all items of a category with `store.find('category', category_id)`. `category.items` now holds all my items, but I just want to display like 5 items, or reverse them, or whatever. Basically I want to manipulate the each loops data.

Comment: Ok, so is this data being fetched from the model hook on your route? Or are you calling store.find() from elsewhere?

Comment: The model for the current route is set within the router. But I need an additional model (last items), which is set in the controller (by `recentItems: function() { return this.store.find('items'); }`).

Comment: Ok I see. I've just updated my original answer - hope that answers your question!

Comment: I see. Thanks. But is there no other way to manipulate an instance, rather to create an own? I mean, why not just returning a collection object which has some methods like `limit`, `reverse`, etc.? Is there a particular reason?

Comment: There may well be, just not that I'm aware of. Have a look through the [ArrayProxy documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html) to see what methods you have available to you. Hopefully one of those will do the job.