# HandleBars limit {{#each arr}}

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I have am working with Handlebars in BigCommerce Stencil and I am wondering if I can limit the items produced by an `{{ #each arr }}` loop.

```
    {{#each categories}}
        <li class="navPages-item category-{{name}} category-{{id}}">
            <a class="navPages-action" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
```

That is my code. I can see solutions like this: [limit results of each in handlebars.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377700/limit-results-of-each-in-handlebars-js) but i dont know if i can use register helper somehow in Stencil

looking for something like `{{#each categories limit:10}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest another block helper within the `{{#each}}` to limit the array by index. For example, if you wanted to return the first 4 categories:

```
{{#each categories}}
    {{#if @index '<' 4}}
        <li class="navPages-item category-{{name}} category-{{id}}">
            <a class="navPages-action" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
        </li>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: It gives me this error "Error: #if requires exactly one argument
"

Comment: If the syntax above doesn't work try:

`{{#ifLt @index 4}}` or {{#lt @index 4}}` for some newer flavors of Handlebars

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and this works in Iterable:

```
{{#each categories}}
    {{#lt @index 4}}
        <li class="navPages-item category-{{name}} category-{{id}}">
            <a class="navPages-action" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
        </li>
    {{/lt}}
{{/each}}
```